# CreateRegistration with generic parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have an generic implementation of my entity reader and writer. I want to create an registration of these to the same instance. But this fails with the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

```
var registration = Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(typeof (EntityFrameworkRepository<>), container);
container.AddRegistration(typeof (IUnitOfWork), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof (IEntityWriter<>), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof (IEntityReader<>), registration);
```

My implementation type signature is as follows:

```
internal sealed class EntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity> : IEntityWriter<TEntity>, IEntityReader<TEntity>, IUnitOfWork where TEntity : Entity 
{
     // ...
}
```

Is generics not supported in the `CreateRegistation(..)` or should I just wire them up like (probably will throw an lifestyle warning)?

```
container.Register(typeof (IUnitOfWork), typeof (EntityFrameworkRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof (IEntityWriter<>), typeof (EntityFrameworkRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof (IEntityReader<>), typeof (EntityFrameworkRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're missing a few pre condition checks here, because you can't create `Registration` objects for open-generic types. A `Registration` instance is specific for a closed-generic or non-generic type. This means that both `CreateRegistration(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>), ...` and `AddRegistration(typeof(IUnitOfWork), ...` are not valid calls.

I understand what you are trying to do, you want to have the same repository instance during a request, independently whether someone uses it as a writer or a reader. That is obvious, because Simple Injector will throw an exception telling you that you have a [Torn Lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html).

To apply this design, you will have to define two generic adapters, from each generic abstraction to the generic repository as follows:

```
public class EnityWriterAdapter<T> : IEntityWriter<T>
{
    public EntityWriterAdapter(EntityFrameworkRepository<T> repository) { ... }
}

public class EnityReaderAdapter<T> : IEntityReader<T>
{
    public EnityReaderAdapter(EntityFrameworkRepository<T> repository) { ... }
}
```

Now the registration can become the following:

```
container.Register(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>),
    typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof(IEntityWriter<>), typeof(EntityWriterAdapter<>));
container.Register(typeof(IEntityReader<>), typeof(EntityReaderAdapter<>));
```

Note that I'm unsure what to do with the `IUnitOfWork` registration, because it's unclear to me which closed `EntityFrameworkRepository<T>` should get injected into consumers that expect `IUnitOfWork`. There seems to be some ambiguity in this.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I think I just write another class for the  `IUnitOfWork` and register it explicit with `Lifestyle.Scoped` I just thought I wanted to combine it all into one implementation for quickness.

Comment: There is no overload for `container.Register(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);` using Simple Injector 3.0.5

Comment: @janhartmann: I'm sorry. You should use `Register(Type, Type, Lifestyle)`. See my update.